# Where did the screen options menu go?

Tags: wp-admin, screen-options

Where did the screen options menu go? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the new "improved" admin interface.

Screenshots from the dashboard page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I still got them in same place. Which version of wp you have? Where are you (post, pages , menus)?

Comment: I'm on the dashboard

Comment: Also, I'm running 3.3-beta1, which is probably where the issue is coming from

Comment: ticket filed: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18920

Comment: i havent played with 3.3 beta yet. Sorry i cant help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, they decided to move it under the un-helpful "help" menu in the main admin bar.

[image]